VSCode version control diff compare - taking alot of time for certain files
We're using Gitlab for version control, and in VSCode when I've done changes to the file "CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml" in local and doing the diff to the branch, it take a lot of time to show me the differences, we're talking about 10 minutes or even more sometimes. We have a good number of custom labels but it should not take that long...
This also happens with certain translation files, like "fr_BE.translation-meta.xml". What is strange is that it doesn't take that long with other translations files that are as big, but it takes much longer with this one. Why could this be happening with some specific files, when analyzing the differences?
My colleague's VSCode has the same configuration and his loads much faster. Thanks very much for your help!

Have you checked the extension repo issues page to see if it's an existing problem?

I figured it out, it had to do with the the Diff Algorithm used in VSCode. It seems that the default one is the "Advanced" one, but it works poorly with certain big files (and I say certain because it's completely random - it gets stuck with some big files and it's smooth with others, which makes finding the issue altogether more confusing.
So, I changed my algorithm to "legacy":

And now it works smoothly!

This worked for me (but I also had to disable a bunch of extensions as well).
